# How do I control the order of nameserver addresses in resolv.conf?

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns, resolvconf

I need to re-order /etc/resolv.conf to list the nameserver provided by eth1 dhcp before the nameserver provided by eth0 dhcp on a 12.04 server (no NetworkManager).

I edited /etc/resolveconf/interface-order and replaced its 'eth*' entry with;

```
eth1
eth0
```

Then tried `resolvconf -u`, ifdown'ed and ifup'ed each interface, `dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`, `service networking restart` and rebooted.  None of this had any effect on the order of resolv.conf.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resolvconf records have names that follow the pattern

```
IFACE.CONFIGURER
```

So to force eth1* records to come before other eth* records you need to replace

```
eth*
```

with

```
eth1*
eth*
```

After making this change, do

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```